# Facebook Business page - Unsupported get request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have admin access to a Business Facebook page, I created an app under the same account, when I then try to use the Graph API Explorer under that application using the access token generated I get:

get/v2.5/{client-name}/

"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }

I have full access so I do not know why I am getting a error. This normally works fine when I try it on a standard Facebook page, is there something extra I need to do for Business pages?

Comment: are you trying with an app token, user token or page token? and what is the client-name/page-name exactly?

Comment: The error almost always means 'you're trying to access something that the access token can't access', and it's rarely incorrect in my experience - most likely, the page is restricted, isn't published yet, you're using a token from a user who can't see it, etc

Comment: I am trying with the app token, I have page admin access to my client. Is there something special with business Facebook accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying with an App Token, i assume that the Page is restricted by age or location. In that case, you have to use a User Token or Page Token of a user who is allowed to see the Page and its content.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/